# RSA and other security features

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, rsa

Mine is an asp.net website on c#.

I have to perform an action and want to authorize and authenticate before performing that action because it is very crititcal.

I can provide normal user and password. but besides that how can i ensure that its secure ??

Any more levels of security features i can provide.

how can i implement RSA ?? in such a scenario?

Comment: You can use diffie- helman algotithm that allow you to use meccanism to exchange a simmetric crittography Key... you can read somethjing on wikypedia

Comment: DH algorithm will allow me to encrypt the password and create keys at both end. I dont think I want that. What I want is when a person who's authorized to perform a particular critical action on my website , how do I make sure that the person is genuine and not someone who's got access to his machine or hacked the password and logged in with genuine person account. What apart from username/password can I come up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get terms straight to make sure I understand your question.

RSA is an algorithm for encryption.  What you have asked for is authentication and authentication.

RSA Inc., the company, provides products including 2-factor authentication.

Encryption : a means of preventing anyone without the proper key from reading a message or channel

Authentication : evidence that an agent is acting on behalf of a particular real user

Authorization : evidence that a user or agent at the other end of the channel can legitimately request an exercise of power

2-factor authentication : proof of authenticity by two channels.  This can be stronger evidence if the two channels are independent.

There are a few ways to gain a level of confidence that the machine sending you messages is acting on behalf of the user (and not just malware installed on their computer or someone peeking over their shoulder) and that the user is who they say they are.

Multiple independent channels are a good way.  If you can reliably get the user's cell phone number then having them provide one set of credentials via a webpage, and then sending them a confirmation SMS with a link with an embedded secret, will establish a second channel.  Malware on their computer can spoof one channel, but only if an attacker can get malware on both devices, would you get an authentication false positive.

Comment: this is exactly what I mean. I want Authentication and Authorization I thought RSA could be useful to provide encryption.
If you could provide more on the confirmation SMS and more such ways. I just want to make sure that the user who is authorizing is actually the user who's supposed to and not someone who's hacked or have accidental access.

Comment: @prateekmalpani.  Yes, encryption can help prevent eavesdropping on a channel so has very little to do with authentication or authorization in practice though can help with man-in-the-middle attacks where a message is changed in-flight.  Related algorithms, called signature algorithms (such as DSA) can help confirm that a message came from someone who knows a key, so can help authenticate.

Comment: What I want is when a person who's authorized to perform a particular critical action on my website , how do I make sure that the person is genuine and not someone who's got access to his machine or hacked the password and logged in with genuine person account. What apart from normal windows based authentication can I come up with? –

Comment: @prateekmalpani, you need a second independent channel for verification.  SMS is one good option for a 2nd channel where you can reliably get the user's cell phone number.  Where they're feasible, security tokens are a fine option too : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token .  Banks often send snail mail to make sure the person is aware of changes that have taken place which can't prevent hacks, but does make it hard to automatically subvert many accounts for long. Some swear by captchas and questions like mother's maiden name to filter out machines but I'm skeptical of those.

Comment: Hmm... I researched more on 2-factor authentication and RSASecurId helped a lot. Thank you very much. Also SMS - based authentication is a good option. :)

Answer (score 1):

RSA is one of the most popular choices for signature based authentication. For example you can use with SSH. The problem is correctly integrating such an algorithm into a protocol.

The simplest solution is probably using SSL/TLS with a client certificate.

The [SslStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=VS.100).aspx) might offer what you need. In particular the constructor overload that takes a `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` and a `LocalCertificateSelectionCallback` looks promising.

Comment: can you provide me some links where I can research and implement this?

Comment: @prat SslStream looks promising.